# Google Earth 64-bit heavily pixelated in 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, google-earth

I installed Google Earth 64-bit on 14.04 LTS using commands at the following link:
http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/install-google-earth-in-ubuntu-1404.html

The application would open but only display heavily pixelated images.

Comment: So you're posting a fix? You should post the answer as an answer and accept it as such.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by going to tools/options/3D view, and unchecked the "compress" option.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
Open Google - Options -  tools - in 3D view graphics mode enable Direct X -
Apply - close and restart Google.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an Open GL graphics card, switch to Direct X under Tools-->Options.

Worked on my laptop which only has built-in Intel graphics.